# Как создать RSA (PEM 1024 bit) пару ключей на Objective-C или Apple Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, ios, rsa, key

Доброе время суток, в общем нужно создать RSA (PEM 1024 bit) пару ключей, пробовал разные варианты, но проблема в том, что как оказалось под iOS это большая редкость, пробовал таким образом:

[Способ #1](https://gist.github.com/lkdocs/6526914)

[Способ #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223275/3429345)

Но это не то что нужно, они создаются в HEX нужен PEM, либо же как можно преобразовать ключ в PEM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось реализовать с помощью [библиотеки](https://github.com/hohl/MIHCrypto).